# Common factor in some cases

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
switch (c) {
    case '-': break;
    case '0': e = expr(j).reduce(C1); e=not(e); a = and(a, e); break;
    case '1': e = expr(j).reduce(C1); a = and(a, e); break;
    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected cube value, " + c);
}
```

The cases 0 and 1 are only different by `not`. I do not like to encode the necessity to `invert` into the arguments of the `and` function,

```
switch (c) {
    case '-': break;
    case '0': a = and(true, a, e); break;
    case '1': a = and(false, a, e); break;
    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected cube value, " + c);
}
```

because this will need a conditional `if (invert) e = inv(e);` in the function, whereas we already established the need to invert when resolved the switch.

I mean that in `case1` you know that you do not need any `inv`. In `case0`, you know that you need one. If you now merge the cases, you will need one more `if` to resolve between `case1` (`inv` is not needed) and `case0` (`inv` is needed) once again.

Comment: Could you provide some more context about this code? What is `a` and `e`? What does `and` though? What does `expr(j).reduce(C1)` do? You don't need to provide the code for them, just explain what it is doing and what types you are using.

Comment: Are `a`, `e` booleans or some more exotic structure?

Comment: @rolfl They are exotic booleans.

Comment: I agree with @SimonAndréForsberg, and I suspect you may have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/148099). It looks like you are trying to do arithmetic based on a string representation of some numbers. Maybe `BigInteger` is appropriate? I encourage you to post the entire function, probably as a separate question referencing this one.

Comment: Your question is essentially the same as a previous question you already asked. You got the same result then. I'm voting to close as duplicate. If you disagree then please tell me what's different with this question.

Comment: @200_success Yes, I think it is XY problem. I ask you to optimize the code as it is, you keep insisting that I must change the type. Exploiting other types is not allowed. Ok?

Comment: @Val `if (c == '-') handleThatcase(); else duplicateOfYourPreviousQuestion();`

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg You are right.

Answer (score 4):

There are two significantly different ways I can think of to rewrite your code.

The first is to put `case '0'` and `case '1'` together by letting one case 'fall through', and then using the ternary operator with in the code to see if we should invert or not.

```
switch (c) {
    case '-': break;
    case '0': // fall through to execute the same code as below
    case '1': 
         e = expr(j).reduce(C1);
         // Using the ternary operator to determine whether or not e should go through not first.
         a = and(a, c == '0' ? not(e) : e);
         break;
    default: throw new Exception("Unexpected cube value, " + c);
}
```

The other approach is to skip the switch and use if-else

```
if (c == '0' || c == '1') {
     e = expr(j).reduce(C1);
     a = and(a, c == '0' ? not(e) : e); // Again, using the ternary operator.
}
else if (c != '-') 
    throw new Exception("Unexpected cube value, " + c);
```

There might be even better ways to rewrite this code, if I would know more context about it.

I agree that you should **not** move the logic of inverting `e` to the `and` method.

Explanation of the **ternary operator**:

```
a = and(a, c == '0' ? not(e) : e);
```

This is the same thing as:

```
if (c == '0')
     a = and(a, not(e));
else 
     a = and(a, e);
```

A more detailed explanation can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Java)

Comment: Your idea to use extra if-else right in the `fallthrough` case is better than mine to pull if-else into the and. But, it does not resolve my concern that if-else for invert must be resolved by cases and using extra if-else is bad (cyclomatic complexity, pipeline stalls and discards). I know what is the ternary operator. It is the same as if-else and I do not think that it is better than if-else. Thanks.

Comment: @Val Your question was quite unclear so it was hard to tell what level of experience you had, and what you are actually asking.

Comment: Not clear? Do you see that `not` in the common pattern? It is not ok. Merging the cases with additional `if` is also not ok.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Simon's answer (which I believe will be more than great for 99.99% of users).....

... actually, I have looked though the code, and I don't understand enough of it to make sense of the right answer:

- why do you do the map-reduce at all if `a = and(a,e)` will be 'false' if `a` starts off 'false`?
- the map-reduce (two method calls) are far, far more expensive than the switch and conditionals outside the methods... this loop does not need to be optimized any more.
- The 'boolean-like' variables `a`, `e` are not well described at all.

Without knowing more about the code and it's context, I can think of only one thing that **may** help, and this is an extension of Simon's answer:

```
if (((c - '0')) >> 1 == 0) { // reduce cyclomatic complexity by 1.
    // '0' is 0x30, (c - '0') will end up with 0 for '0' and 1 for '1' - anything else is wrong
    e = expr(j).reduce(C1);
    a = and(a, c == '0' ? not(e) : e); // Again, using the ternary operator.
} else if (c != '-') 
    throw new Exception("Unexpected cube value, " + c);
```

Any other suggestions would just be wild guesses.

**EDIT**

```
public static void char01() {
    for (char c = Character.MIN_VALUE; c <= Character.MAX_VALUE; c++) {
        if ((c - '0') >> 1 == 0) {
            System.out.println("This matches '" + c + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

produces:

```
This matches '0'
This matches '1'
```

Comment: `reduce` is just a placeholder for some another function. Sorry for a confusing name.

Comment: LSB of `c-'0'` is 0 or 1 for cases 0 and 1. But (`c-'0'` >> 1 != 0) passes if `c` is `2` or larger. How do your single out cases `0` and `1` this way?

Comment: @Val - it works... do the math: See my edit:

Comment: @Val perhaps it should be `>> 1 == 0`

Comment: Ahh... yes.... copy-paste problem/

Comment: I looked the cyclomatic complexity article and it says that complexity of `if (a)` = complexity of `if (a | b)` because the number of branches rather than conditions that matters. I believe that that after compiler optimizations, `if (((c - '0')) >> 1 == 0)` is identical to `if (c == '1' || c == '0')`. The predicates are linear in both cases. The complexity is the same. What really affects the performance and code complexity is the number of branches.

Comment: In `if(c=='1' || c == '0') { ... }` there are three code paths, complexity 3. In `if (((c - '0')) >> 1 == 0)` there are only 2 - complexity 2. Promise. With the former there are two ways to get in to the block... with the latter there's only one.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15240922/cyclomatic-complexity-with-compound-conditions-and-short-circuiting